# mysql InnoDB: Unable to lock ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo0 error: 13

Tags: mysql, innodb

```
2022-07-31T10:46:33.631091Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 1268525

2022-07-31T10:46:33.680919Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.

2022-07-31T10:46:35.911807Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo0 error: 13

2022-07-31T10:46:35.911857Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012894] [InnoDB] Unable to open './#innodb_redo/#ib_redo0' (error: 11).

2022-07-31T10:46:35.911872Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Cannot open a file.

2022-07-31T10:46:36.124480Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine

2022-07-31T10:46:36.124674Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.

2022-07-31T10:46:36.124690Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

This instance of mysql has been running fine for over a year on ubuntu.  The server crashed and generated a crash log - now I get this error when trying to restart the server.  I have looked at other posts and have verified/tried:
A) There is not another mysql instance running
B) AppArmor has been edited to allow access (nothing has changed & re-verified)
```

Looking at the file it is trying to lock, nothing jumps out at me on why it can not lock it:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql 3276800 Jul 29 06:20 '#ib_redo0'*

Suggestions?  What am I missing?

Comment: Please show the permissions on both the file and the directory it is in.